# WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] Manager#logs is deprecated. Use Chrome::Driver#logs instead

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I get the above warning when executing this line:

`logs = page.driver.browser.manage.logs.get(:browser)`

its not clear from the deprecation notice how to fix this

This is happening on Selenium 4.1.0

Comment: Is there an associated issue or ticket to reference? This could be a gem problem that needs to be patched.

Comment: see note this is a fairly old version of selenium and I could find no mention of this deprecation anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember they adjusted the API a while back. On selenium-webdriver 4.8.x I am using:

```
page.driver.browser.logs.get(:browser)
```

Basically just use `browser.logs` instead of `browser.manage.logs`